# How to add a another value to a key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

First I'm sorry this might be a dumb question but I'm trying to self learn python and I can't find the answer to my question.

I want to make a phonebook and I need to add an email to an already existing name. That name has already a phone number attached. I have this first code:

```
phonebook = {}
phonebook ['ana'] = '12345'
phonebook ['maria']= '23456' , 'maria@gmail.com'

def add_contact():
       name = raw_input ("Please enter a name:")
       number = raw_input ("Please enter a number:")
       phonebook[name] = number
```

Then I wanted to add an email to the name "ana" for example: ana: 12345, ana@gmail.com. I created this code but instead of addend a new value (the email), it just changes the old one, removing the number:

```
def add_email():
       name = raw_input("Please enter a name:")
       email = raw_input("Please enter an email:")
       phonebook[name] = email
```

I tried  .append() too but it didn't work. Can you help me? And I'm sorry if the code is bad, I'm just trying to learn and I'm a bit noob yet :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append` isn't working because the dictionary's values are not lists.  If you make them lists here by placing them in `[...]`:

```
phonebook = {}
phonebook ['ana'] = ['12345']
phonebook ['maria'] = ['23456' , 'maria@gmail.com']
```

`append` will now work:

```
def add_contact():
   name = raw_input("Please enter a name:")
   number = raw_input("Please enter a number:")
   phonebook[name].append(number)
```